# How to write a 'WHERE IN' statement in SQL with a CASE

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I have a WHERE clause in a SQL stored procedure and passing in a integer value. What i am trying to achieve is that when the number 0 is passed in, the query will take a list of numbers from 1 -10 and use these values. This is my code.

```
AND [COLUMN_NAME] in ( CASE WHEN @PARAMETER <> 0 THEN @PARAMETER
        ELSE (SELECT [EVENT_ID] FROM [TABLE_NAME]) END )
```

the line below returns 
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10

```
SELECT [EVENT_ID] FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

I am not seeing any results however. Any help is much appreciated.

D

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Sorry, in the else part of the statement, how can i pass in more than one integer value? if i write `ELSE (1,2,3)` i get a syntax error

Comment: I don't follow you either. Can you re-formulate your question? Perhaps with a better explanation of the problem you're trying to solve, and some concrete/practical examples?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It looks like in the ELSE Part, OP wants to generate a comma-separated list of EVENT_IDs, which so happen to be from 1 to 10.

Comment: Sounds like it could be that `CASE` can't give a scalar in one case and a tuple in another, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: @Shiva: I don't think he wants a comma-separated list of anything, but a tuple to use with `IN`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is comma-separated because it is part of the IN Clause. In effect, what I think OP wants is to generate the IN CLAUSE for Parameter <> 0 and that in clause will have the output of the select, which should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. So that the last part of SQL reads as => AND [COLUMN_NAME] in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 )

Comment: @Shiva: Okay when you say "comma-separated" that instills images of a _string_, because although a tuple's elements will appear to be comma-delimited if you write it out by hand in a query, when you use a subquery instead there is no internal stage of processing in which these commas magically make a re-appearance. Two different ways of looking at it, I suppose, but I wouldn't be so "lexical" in my thought process. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. LOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE
  (@Parameter != 0 and [Column_Name] = @Parameter)
  OR
  (@Parameter = 0 and [Column_Name] in (SELECT [EVENT_ID] FROM [TABLE_NAME])
```

Comment: @Hiky Bill's solution works for what you are trying to do. I just tested it.